# Add Hyperlink to Word Bookmark

Tags: vbscript, hyperlink, ms-word

Im struggling with adding a hyperlink to a Bookmark with VBS.

The script is used to retrieve data from the active domain directory and set up a company signature for each user however I want the email address to be a hyperlink and clickable.

I tried placing this somewhere:
doc.Hyperlinks.Add(ActiveDocument.bookmarks("Email").Range, ,objUser.mail, , objUser.mail)

But no matter where I placed it I only got errors.

This is what I have so far just plain text.

```
strTemplate = "\\w2k8srv1\NETLOGON\Signatures\test.docx"

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(strTemplate)
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

With objDoc.Bookmarks
    .Item("FullName").Range.Text = objUser.cn
    .Item("Title").Range.Text = objUser.title
    .Item("Telephone").Range.Text = objUser.telephoneNumber
    .Item("Email").Range.Text = objUser.mail
End With
Set selection = objDoc.Range()
With objWord.EmailOptions.EmailSignature
    .EmailSignatureEntries.Add "Sign", selection
    .NewMessageSignature = "Sign"
    .ReplyMessageSignature = "Rare"
End With

objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

So I'm simply trying to add a hyperlink to the bookmark "Email" with the value of objUser.mail.

Comment: WHAT errors do you get? Which line of code triggers them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code like:

```
.Item("Email").Range.Text = objUser.mail
```

does not add the content to the bookmark; it inserts it after the bookmark. If you want the email address to be inserted as a hyperlink you could use code like:

```
With objDoc
    .Bookmarks("FullName").Range.Text = objUser.cn
    .Bookmarks("Title").Range.Text = objUser.Title
    .Bookmarks("Telephone").Range.Text = objUser.telephoneNumber
    .Hyperlinks.Add .Bookmarks("Email").Range, objUser.mail
End With
```

Note that .Hyperlinks.Add takes other arguments as well; I've omitted them for brevity.